# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins

I am trying to build new item in jenkins (1st time) to run autotest in maven.
I configure the jenkins and press build now.
There is a problem I can't find the answer and ask for help please.
This is the error in the console :

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ miron ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/3.0.0-M5/maven-surefire-common-3.0.0-M5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  43.979 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-23T10:29:40+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "Regression" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project miron: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M5 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:pom:3.0.0-M5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/3.0.0-M5/maven-surefire-common-3.0.0-M5.pom: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.192.215, repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.196.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

I am working from work (company).

My POM :

```
<build>
  
  <plugins>
 
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
           <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
  
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

</plugins>
  
  </build>
```

Can someone help me solve it please ?

Comment: First text is better than images.. second you likeley have a network issue based on the timeout...Furthermore I strongly recommend to use a repository manager ...

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by saying "I strongly recommend to use a repository manager" ?